# Process for finding UMVU estimator

Tags: self-study, intuition, estimators, mathematical-statistics

I've been working on a problem from Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a Core Course by Keener. I spent a few hours on it making very little progress before caving and looking up the solution. I don't see what the justification for their solution is or what the intuition is that would lead to it.

The question is $\S{4.7}$ Problem 8:

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid absolutely continuous variables with common density $f_\theta$, $\theta > 0$, given by 
>   $$
> f_\theta = \begin{cases} \frac{\theta}{x^2}, & x > 0 \\[6pt] 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
> $$
>   find the UMVU estimator for $g(\theta)$ if $g(\theta) / \theta^n \rightarrow 0 $ as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$ and $g$ is differentiable.

I had no idea where to start with this problem, and ended up trying various approaches before looking up the solution which was $\min(x_i)$.

Comment: There must be a typo because your density does not integrate properly. It has an infinite mass.

Comment: I wonder if it said $x>\theta$ rather than $x>0.$ The latter does not make sense.